# Issue in creating Zip file using glob.glob

Tags: glob, zip

I am creating a Zip file from a folder (and subfolders). it works fine and creates a new .zip file also but I am having an issue while using glob.glob. It is reading all files from the desired folder (source folder) and writing to the new zip file but the problem is that it is, however, adding subdirectories, but not adding files form the subdirectories.

I am giving user an option to select the filename and path as well as filetype also (Zip or Tar). I don;t get any problem while creating .tar.gz file, but when use creates .zip file, this problem comes across.

Here is my code:

```
for name in (Source_Dir):
    for name in glob.glob("/path/to/source/dir/*" ):
        myZip.write(name, os.path.basename(name), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

myZip.close()
```

Also, if I use code below:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(Source_Dir):
        myZip.write(os.path.join(dirpath, filename) os.path.basename(filename))        

myZip.close()
```

Now the 2nd code taks all files even if it inside the folder/ subfolders, creates a new .zip file and write to it without any directory strucure. It even does not take dir structure for main folder and simply write all files from main dir or subdir to that .zip file.

Can anyone please help me or suggest me. I would prefer glob.glob rather than the 2nd option to use.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Akash

Answer (score 1):

Glob by design does not expand into subdirectories.  It follows UNIX style path rules and expansions see the documentation for [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) for more information. If you want to get at the subdirectories you need to add it to the path.  This example will get everything at one level down.

```
for name in (Source_Dir):
    for name in glob.glob("/path/to/source/dir/*/*" ):
        myZip.write(name, os.path.basename(name), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

myZip.close()
```

Doug Hellman has an excellent discussion [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/glob/).  If you are not using the pattern features of glob  (like *.txt  for all text files or *[0-9].txt  for all text files that have a number before the extension)  then I think your os.walk solution is better